# Exclude Folder in URL with Regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I would like to perform an A/B Test with different URL Structures.

```
/URL-part-a/URL-part-b/thankyou

/URL-part-a/URL-part-c/thankyou
```

I would like Google Analytics Keep the goal for /thankyou, so I would like to let it read it like

```
/URL-part-a/*****/thankyou
```

Is there a way to solve this with regex? If so, how could it be done?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `(^|/)URL-part-a/[^/]+/thankyou$`

Comment: /URL-part-a/.*/thankyou, would this be easier?

Comment: Probably. Just `.*` will match anything, even `/`, and will thus match `/URL-part-a/U/R/L/-/p/a/r/t/-/c/thankyou`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
/URL-part-a/(.*?)/thankyou
```